# How to rebuild all indexes in a certain database where number of records in the index is less than certain count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I would like to rebuild all indexes in a given database where number of records in the index less than certain count lets say 100k

How can i write such a SQL server 2014 query ?

Ty very much

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know where to get the number of rows in an index, for example?

Comment: @AaronBertrand well there are so many index rebuild queries on the internet however none takes into consideration number of elements in the index

Comment: Programmers take solution A and solution B and make them work together to solve problem C.

Comment: Would the number of rows in the index be the number of rows in the table? Google is failing me, am I missing something?

Comment: @CSharper i suppose that should be correct. i mean number of rows in the table :)

Comment: @CSharper Not necessarily. There are filtered indexes, for example, which could contain a very small percentage of the number of rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

A little powershell goes a long way

```
import-module sqlps;

$srv = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server 'your-server';
$db = $srv.databases['your-db'];
foreach ($tbl in $db.Tables) {
  foreach ($idx in $tbl.Indexes) {
    foreach ($prtn in $idx.PhysicalPartitions) {
      if ($prtn.RowCount -gt 100000) {
        if ($idx.IsPartitioned) {
          $idx.Rebuild($prtn.PartitionNumber);
        }
        else {
          $idx.Rebuild();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to rebuild if and only if the number of rows in aggregate for the index is above the threshold, add the rowcount for all of the partitions together and call rebuild() on the index if it exceeds the threshold.

Comment: can you provide tsql that would be great ty very much

Comment: I could, but I won't. The T-SQL for this is a pain in the ass. Each of those foreach loops above would be a cursor (and no, I'm not in the "cursors are always evil" camp) and it would be a horrid nest of dynamic SQL. Luckily you said that you're on 2014, so this script should be able to run as is (either from the command line or through the SQL Agent).

Comment: I tried from SQL server management studio but it failed :D i should check it

Comment: You can't run it from SSMS directly. Either right click on the database and choose "start powershell here" or run powershell directly.